# Bootstrap buttons won't display inline-block

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm really beginner with CSS and can't figure out how to align bootstrap drop-down buttons horizontally. Here is a code snippet of my project: https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-resonance-80id9?file=/src/App.js

The idea is to have them aligned horizontally at the top of the page, with equal space between them and between the borders, so they're spread out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change display mode :

```
.buttonContainer {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

this [flex guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) can helps you
[image: Edit laughing-lewin-8in6f]